How to locate the file that defines specific symbol through #define in C++?
For example, I want to locate the header file that defines _WIN32_WINNT, how can I do? I tried g++ -E but it does not work.
Note that there may be multiple definitions of the same symbol. I want to show them all and show the effective definition.

I'd use an IDE for this.

_WIN32_WINNT suggests you are using Windows. VisualStudio IDE has a feature to locate the definition of a #define (right click a symbol -> "Go To Definition").

Either an IDE or a "search for text in file utility" for your OS.  Also note that defines can be part of the build environment as well as #define

I'm not able to test it right now, but try using -E -dD. That should include the macro definitions in the preprocessed output, and you can read them in conjunction with the # lines in the output which tell you the file that each chunk of code came from.

@NateEldredge That is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!
